# How to dynamically add an ng-click to span?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I should add ng-click directive in a dynamically generated span. The span wraps the selected text.

```
range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var span = document.createElement("span");
$(span) .addClass("comment")
           .attr("id", short_id +"_"+ n_comment)
           .attr("ng-click", "showComment()")
           .append(range.extractContents());
range.insertNode(span);
```

The above code gets the selection and wraps it with the span, but the `ng-click` doesn't work.
Since the angular directive is dynamically generated, it should be compiled with `$compile`, but in this case I don't know how to execute the compilation.

How can I solve? Thank you all.

Comment: doesn't work is such a broad description, do you get an error in the browser console (either during rendering of the spans or when actually clicking on them). What is stopping you from adding the event the "old fashioned" way?

Comment: I haven't errors in the console (neither during rendering and when I click). I'm pretty sure that the problem concerns the compilation. If I don't use `$compile`, ng-click is considered as simple html instead of an angular directive. But my question is: how to use `$compile` in this case?

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but there's likely an easier way of accomplishing this.  It looks like you're mixing jQuery with your Angular.

Comment: It seems like you're taking a non-angular approach to dynamically generating spans.  The whole point of angular is to have your HMTL dynamically adapt to your data.  This seems like the perfect place for `ng-repeat` in the markup.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you're right. Indeed I use `ng-repeat` in other parts of the application. But in this case I didn't know how to integrate it. In the application the user can make annotation to scientific articles, so he can select pieces of document and make annotation on them. Generally I use `ng-repeat` when I have data and I want to display it on the view. Maybe in my case `ng-repeat` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by my own with this code:

```
range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var span = document.createElement("span");
$(span) .addClass("comment")
           .attr("id", short_id +"_"+ n_comment)
           .attr("ng-click", "showComment()")
           .append(range.extractContents());
range.insertNode(span);
getScope(span);
```

And the function `getScope`:

```
function getScope(el){
    var $scope = angular.element(el).scope();
    $scope.view(el);
}
```

In this way I get the scope of the span, and in the `view()` function I compile the dynamically generated html:

```
$scope.view = function(element){
    $compile(element)($scope);
}
```

After compiling the element, ng-click works.
Thank you all.

Comment: Why are you using angular at all then? This kind of defeats the purpose of it, and you'd be better off using jquery.

Comment: If you mean using `$(element).click(function(){});` you're right, but I have a big application and for click event I use always `ng-click`, so I prefer to use angular to follow the pattern of the entire application.